# Installing heroku CLI plugin on an M1 Mac gives yarn error

Tags: heroku, apple-m1, heroku-cli

I'm working on adding Heroku's new enhanced certificates to (hopefully) make our Google Data Studio reports less prone to failing when Heroku automatically refresh database certificates. Heroku provide a guide: [Connecting to a Heroku Postgres Database with Enhanced Certificates](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-enhanced-certificates).

The first step is to install the *data* CLI plugin: `heroku plugins:install data`

For me that fails with yarn errors:

```
›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.63.4 to 7.64.0.
Installing plugin data... failed
Error: yarn add @heroku-cli/plugin-data@latest --non-interactive --mutex=file:/Users/timregan/.local/share/heroku/yarn.lock --preferred-cache-folder=/Users/timregan/Library/Caches/heroku/yarn --check-files --registry=https://registry.npmjs.org exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/heroku/7.63.4/libexec/node_modules/@oclif/plugin-plugins/lib/yarn.js:31:28)
```

I do not understand. Why is yarn involved? Is there a yarn or brew command I should be invoking instead of `heroku plugins:install data`?

(EDIT: I now suspect this is an Apple M1 architecture issue. I get the same error when trying to install other Heroku CLI plugins.)

Comment: I've submitted an issue on the Heroku CLI repo for this: https://github.com/heroku/cli/issues/2074

Comment: did you manage to find a fix for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to overcome this issue after downgrading from Yarn 3 to yarn 1.

For some reason, it does not work with yarn 3 (possibly with yarn 2 as well).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my work around:

```
# Verify this yarn.lock exists
ls /Users/timregan/.local/share/heroku/yarn.lock

# remove the yarn.lock file
rm /Users/timregan/.local/share/heroku/yarn.lock
```

Then attempt to install the CLI plugin again, `heroku plugins:install data`

```
# Verify the plugin was installed  
heroku help data
```

- Note: that I was installing the plugin `data:maintenances` as identified in this [Heroku DevCenter Article: Data Maintenance CLI Plugin Commands](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/data-maintenance-cli-commands#installation)

Comment: I updated the Github Issue @dumbledad created in the  Heroku CLI repo for this: github.com/heroku/cli/issues/2074